# Digital Photograph Forensics Software for Linux

Tags: linux, images, forensics

Is there any forensics software that can handle digital Photograph for linux ?
An opensource software is preferable

Comment: If you don't need a certificate or somtehing like that, just use `dd`...

Comment: I don't assume you mean linux's `dd` command right?

Comment: My interpretation of this question is that the OP wants to take a perfectly intact image file and look at metadata (e.g., time the photograph was taken (as determined by the camera’s clock) and geographic / GPS coordinates), evidence that the image was modified, etc.   However, lacking any such clarification from the OP, this question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

But of course. [Kali Linux](http://www.kali.org/) has many tools ready to use, especially see their "Forensic Tools" [listing](http://tools.kali.org/tools-listing). Almost all the tools are available to download & use in any linux, not just Kali, many are in Debian & others repositories.

You might want to look into gnu's [`ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) to make an image of a hard drive, but I don't think that's what you meant...

Or if you mean recovering images as in "photographs" then something like `photorec` from the [`testdisk`](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) tools could be useful, it can find image files in damaged or deleted filesystems (`testdisk` can too if the filesystem is still generally intact). Or [Foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) should do a similar thing.

After reading a comment, still not 100% sure what you're after, examining an image generally involves viewing it & zooming in. But maybe this tool might be useful: [Binwalk](http://binwalk.org/) - "a tool for searching a given binary image for embedded files and executable code" but I think they mean firmware images...

And you do know that `photorec` can search through any file looking for other files inside it, if that's what you're after.

Otherwise it sounds like you just want to dig through a file with a hex editor, looking for interesting stuff.

Or try `strings filename`?

- After last comment, it's clear this has nothing to do with computer forensics in the regular sense...

I think you probably want to use `gimp` and google "[brighten image in gimp](https://encrypted.google.com/search?&q=brighten%20image%20in%20gimp)" or "[enhance image in gimp](https://encrypted.google.com/search?&q=enhance%20image%20in%20gimp)"

Comment: I mean photographs and I'm not talking about restoring deleted picture, I'm talking about analysing an existing picture.

Comment: Isn't "analyzing an existing picture" the same as taking a close look at it, zooming in and whatnot?

Comment: If the image is clear enough , but it is not and filters in GIMP are not helping, thus a I need a bit more specialized tool.

Comment: @OssamaNasser if that's what you wanted you should have updated your question to say so.

Answer (score -1):

There is a comprehensive set of free forensic tools called: Ghiro. It might be worth having a look at them.

There's a bit of a learning curve, but this suite can batch check entire directories or just one file.  There are quite a few tools and I am still learning it myself.

A link to Ghiro is below, 
Not being "packaged" and part of repositories I know about at the time of writing, it takes some of dependency-finding to install it.  The documentation is quite good and it is free.

http://www.getghiro.org/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/242754)

Comment: Info updated, I see your point.